# Is it possible to extend string resources lookup in Android?

Tags: android, xml, string, resources, extending

I have a multilanguage application that uses the standard xml files to provide string values in different laguages.

```
...
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-es/strings.xml
res/values-pt/strings.xml
...
```

What I want to do is override the normal behavior of Android to look for a resource somewhere else before looking into the standard xml files.

So when the code calls *getResources().getString()* a custom code would look into an alternative resource file before falling back into the standard getString implementation.

Is there any way to achieve this?

thanks!

Comment: You could derive a  wrapper class doing this call first

Comment: The correct question to ask is "why somewhere else"?

Comment: @André Yes, I should have added that I want to get the same functionality when using string resources from xml files, like _@string/stringKey_.

Comment: @Simon Well it's an attempt to integrate a legacy i18n system that actually works on the same product on other platforms.
Anyway, thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve this?

No. For your own invocations of `getString()`, you can wrap those calls in your own code to check "somewhere else".

Answer (score 0):

The part you intend to achieve is not possible as Android by default would look only i the res folder for the required resources.